# Searching for DAX formula - equivalent to Excel SUMIF

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am searching for a DAX formula.

Specifically:

```
If SOLD (1st column) = count volume (second column), if not SOLD = 0
```

I need to reflect the volume of SOLD in a new column. UNSOLD Volumes should be 0.

I attach the reduced data set.

[image: Data set]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to only perform aggregation when the SOLD_UNSOLD column is equal to "SOLD", otherwise return 0?  If so, the following formula will do this, you'll just need to update the column names accordingly.  The outer `IF` prevents problems resulting from further evaluation (i.e. grand totals) and it's necessary to wrap the column in the `VALUES` function as this will turn the column into a table of the unique values of it.

```
'YourTable'[CountOfSold] =
    IF (
        COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( YourTable[SOLD_UNSOLD] ) ) = 1,
        IF (
            VALUES ( YourTable[SOLD_UNSOLD] ) = "SOLD",
            COUNT ( YourTable[ColumnToAggregate] ),
            0
        ),
        0
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The Excel `SUMIF` is closest to the DAX `SUMX`.

I'm not positive I'm understanding what you are asking for, but I think you'd want something like this:

```
SOLD_VOLUME = SUMX(Table1,
                   IF(Table1[SOLD_UNSOLD] = "SOLD",
                      Table1[DAILY_VOLUME],
                      0
                   )
              )
```

You could also do this with a filter:

```
SOLD_VOLUME = SUMX(
                  FILTER(
                      Table1,
                      Table1[SOLD_UNSOLD] = "SOLD"
                  ),
                  Table1[DAILY_VOLUME]
              )
```