# "COUNTIFS" Do we have similar fun in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have condition where I need to use COUNTIFS, same formula work fine in excel & gives desired output.

I was trying same thing in POWER BI but struggling.

> Data looks like,
>   Part- A1 A1 A1 A1
>   Type- DP DP DP DP
>   Count- 4 4 4 4

Output at each row level should be Count= 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI - countif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442875/power-bi-countif)

Comment: See also [this answer for SUMIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502404/searching-for-dax-formula-equivalent-to-excel-sumif).

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it, below is the solution,

Similar output, COUNTIFS in Power BI

```
Count =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTAX(Input,[Part]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(Input, Input['Part]),
        Input[Type]="DP"
    )
)
```